# What is the best and fastest way to check if the site is online

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have made an app that extract some data of other sites.

Each site has a `Parser` Specific to it.

Now sometimes in the future those sites stop working or may have some problem.

I would like to be able to check each of those site and see if it is online or not.

This check would be triggered when the app start, So I want it to be fast.

I came upp with and easy way to do it, but I wonder if there is still a better way to do it.

Here is my current way of doing it.

```js
static async fetchWithTimeout(url: string, options) {
  const {
    timeout = 8000
  } = options;

  const controller = new AbortController();
  const id = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    ...options,
    signal: controller.signal
  });
  clearTimeout(id);

  return response;
}

static async isOnline(url: string) {
  try {
    console.log(`Sending isOnline request to ${url}`);
    let headers = new Headers({
      Accept: '*/*',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    });
    var data = await httpClient.fetchWithTimeout(url, {
      timeout: 10000,
      headers: headers,
      method: 'GET'
    })
    return data.ok;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And then simple call `await httpClient.isOnline("www.google.se");`

What do you think is the fastest way of doing it

Comment: Your check only checks for a timeout. What if the site does not time out, but returns, say, a 503 error? Would that be considered "down"?

Comment: Well you are right. But this is not the problem I want to think of just yet. But yes you are right I should check for different error code. The problem really is that if the site is down it takes to much time to confirm it that why I added a timeout. Is there really a faster,better way of doing it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a way to check for a timeout faster than the length of the timeout. So what you're doing is correct, except that I would use axios with its timeout settings. That way you can `catch` the error when it times out, which makes you code a bit easier to read. Axios can also catch all those http error codes at the same time.

Comment: You also shouldn’t await the isOnline function for each site, but rather fire it simultaneously for all sites. That way you won’t have to wait 100 second to check 10 sites, but only 10 seconds.

Comment: Well that is one way to yes :)

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is currently written suggests to me that you await the result of every website's timeout check. I.e. if you have 5 websites and your timeout setting is 10 seconds, your app will wait for 50 seconds before starting.

I think there is a more efficient approach. You should make the `fetchWithTimeout` function return a promise with the check result. You can then fire off a timeout check for all 5 sites simultaneously and collect their promises into an array, which then can be resolved with `Promise.all`. Here is the general idea:

```
const fetchWithTimeout = (url, options) => {
    const { timeout = 8000 } = options;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const id = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), timeout);

        fetch(url, {
            ...options,
            signal: controller.signal
        })
            .then((r) => {
                if (r.ok) {
                    resolve({ url, msg: "ok" });
                } else {
                    resolve({ url, msg: "error" });
                }
            })
            .catch((e) => resolve({ url, msg: "error" }));
        clearTimeout(id);
    });
};

const sites = ["https://4.2.2.2", "https://httpstat.us/200", "https://httpstat.us/404"];

Promise.all(sites.map((url) => fetchWithTimeout(url, { timeout: 10000 })))
  .then((result) => {
    const good_sites = result.filter((site) => site.msg === "ok");
    const down_sites = result.filter((site) => site.msg === "error");

    console.log("Good sites:", good_sites);
    console.log("Down sites:", down_sites);
  });
```

Of the three websites `["https://4.2.2.2", "https://httpstat.us/200", "https://httpstat.us/404"]` only google.com will be "up". The first will time out, the last will return a 404. But the main thing is you can check them in just 10 seconds.